# How do I pass variables from a model to a controller to be used on a view in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variable-assignment

I am trying to create my user module in codeigniter and can't figure out how to pass results from a query in my model to a controller that will allow me to use in my view.

Here is my model:

```
public function user() 
        {
            $session = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$user_id LIMIT 1"); 
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $row->first_name;
                $row->id;
                $row->email;
                $row->last_name;
            }

        }
```

and here is my controller. How to do I pass these objects? Or should I be putting them in an array and then passing the array ( still not sure how to pass it ) and then extracting them from the array on my controller?

```
public function edit() 
    {
        $data['first_name'] = $this->session->userdata('first_name');
        $data['profile_icon'] = 'edit';
        $data['profile_breadcrumbs'] = 'Edit Profile';
        $data['main_content'] = 'account/edit';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $session = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        $this->account_model->user();
        if($session)
        {
            //TRYING TO GET OBJECTS
        }
    }
```

I have found similar questions related to this but having a hard time finding exactly what I'm looking for.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you getting so many downvotes? You a bad apple or summin?

Comment: I really don't know, I hope not. It seems like an valid question and seems to be clear and contain code. I still think there should be explanations required for down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
$data['user']=$this->account_model->user();
//populates $data['user'] with the user details based on the session.
$this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
```

The Model:

```
public function user() 
    {
        $session = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$user_id LIMIT 1");
        if($query->num_rows()==1)
        {
           $data = $query->result_array();
           return $data[0];
        //above returns the single row you need to the controller as an array.
        //to the $data['user'] variable.
        } else {
           do something here to handle no return
        }
    }
```

Then in the view your data is accessible via the $user variable, so you could do this:

```
echo 'Hi '.$user['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign it to a variable and work with that:

```
$user = $this->account_model->user();

foreach($user->result() as $row){
    echo $row->name;
}
```

And if you want to pass the data to the view, you have to make sure you load the view last after all of the `$data` has been set:

```
$user = $this->account_model->user();
$data['user'] = $user;
$this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
```

then your user data generated by the model will be available in the view via the `$user` variable.

---

Edit:

Also noticed you aren't `return`ing anything from the model :/

Model:

```
public function user() 
    {
        $session = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$user_id LIMIT 1"); 
        return $query;

    }
```

Controller:

```
$user = $this->account_model->user();
$data['user'] = $user;
$this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
```

View:

```
foreach($user->result() as $row){
    $first_name = $row->first_name;
    $id = $row->id;
    $email = $row->email;
    $last_name = $row->last_name;
}

echo "User id: $id has $first_name as a first name, $last_name as their last name, and $email as their email address";
```

So, your model queries the database, returning the result. The controller calls the function in the model for the data it wants (in this case `user()`) and sends it to the view. The view loops through the query and displays the data.

Comment: Ok that is what I am looking for. The only question I have is the first code chunk you posted goes in the model and replaces my existing foreach statement?

Comment: And make sure your `user()` function actually returns the user!  `$user = $this->account_model->user();` won't help you if your `user()` function does not return anything.

Comment: @LightningWrist I updated the answer; didn't realize you weren't actually returning the data from the model. My example is just an example; there are any number of ways you could do it.